# Chef cookbook execution not working step by step

Tags: chef

My recipe config looks like this:

```
package "scribe" do
  action :install
end

package "supervise-scripts" do
   action :install
end

remote_directory "/var/service/" do
   source "#{node['site-scribe']['cluster']}"
end

Dir.foreach('/var/service') do |dir|
next if dir == '..'|| dir == '.'
  execute "svc_add_#{dir}" do
    command "/usr/bin/svc-add #{dir}"
    not_if { ::Dir.exists?("/var/service/#{dir}/supervise") }
  end

  execute "svc_restart_#{dir}" do
    command "/usr/bin/svc-restart #{dir}"
  end
end
```

And now i have strange behavior.. at first run of chef-client on server its only executing `remote_directory` block and not start `Dir.foreach` loop. At second run it executing `Dir.foreach` normally (always when `remote_directory` wasn't downloaded). Why my loop `Dir.foreach` not starting if `remote_directory` block was executed?

Same behavior is when I remove that `not_if`.

//holosian

Comment: Do the subdirectories of `/var/service` exist prior to the first chef run?

Comment: Yes its exist, and remote_directory is downloading without any problems.. but loop is not executed after that.

Comment: Then I don't now. Otherwise it would be a pretty easy answer (compile phase, when resources are created, vs. run time, where they are executed an the actual subdirectories would be created).

Answer (score 1):

The loop `Dir.foreach` is executed before the remote directory action actually takes place.  Chef executes in two phases.  During the first, all of your recipe code is run, and resources are placed in an array for later evaluation.  In the second phase, those resources are then run to actually do the work.  What is happening in your case, as alluded to by StephenKing, is that:

1. your `remote_directory` block runs, and places a resource on the template to pull down that remote directory.
2. your `Dir.foreach` loop is run, but since the resource for #1 is still in the array (has not been executed yet) there are no children in the `/var/service` directory.  So the loop loops over 0 elements, and exits.
3. On your second run of `chef-client`, you then have values in `/var/service` so the loop works great.

Unless you NEED to do a full convergence in just one run of chef, you really don't have a problem.  Just make sure you use `not_if` and `only_if` statements to ensure that each resource only runs when needed.  However, if you need to do everything in one run, you have to hack a solution.  The easiest option is to force an immediate evaluation of your `remote_directory` resource by doing something like this:

```
remote_directory "/var/service/" do
   source "#{node['site-scribe']['cluster']}"
end.run_action(:create)
```

That will force the action to actually execute during the first phase of chef execution, and then your loop will work.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. actually we used bash script to do the job. But in future i will check your solution.